# Desafio criar menu com solicitação ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Arquivo json produto.json

```
{
    "produto":[
        {"categoria": "#home", "nome": "home"},
        {"categoria": "#fotos", "nome": "fotos"},
        {"categoria": "#contato", "nome": "contato"},
        {"categoria": "#perfil", "nome": "perfil"},
        {"categoria": "#painel", "nome": "painel"}
    ]
}
```

arquivo teste.js

```
$(function(){
    var nome_a = ['home', 'fotos', 'contato', 'perfil', 'painel'];
    var n = '';

    var el = $('ul');
    for(var i = 0; i < nome_a.length; i ++){
        console.log('<li><a>'+nome_a[i]+'</a></li>');
        const y = '<li><a>'+nome_a[i]+'</a></li>';
        el.append(y);
    }
    //configura atribute href no elemento <a>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'produto.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        $('a').each(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.produto.length; i++){
            //console.log(data.produto[i]);
           // n += event.type;
           n += data.produto[i]["categoria"];
        }
        $(this).attr('href', n);
    }) 
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("Erro no carregamento das categorias");
    })
})
```

O que estou fazendo não é de nenhum projeto é apenas um desafio.

O que estou querendo é obter a categoria do produto e adicionar como link no href do elemento `<a>` fazendo solicitação ajax().

A primeira linha de código do arquivo teste.js está criando as tags `<li><a>` com os nomes das categorias da `var nome_a`, e criando com um laço `for()`.

A segunda parte agora é obter as categorias com ajax() e adicionar no atribute href, mas quando faço isso é adicionar todas as categoria em uma única tag `<a>`. Exemplo de resultado: `<a href="#home#fotos#contato...">home</a>`

O que eu quero é fazer com que cada categoria fique em cada tag `<a href="[categoria aqui]">` dentro do href. Alguém aí capaz de obter esse resultado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você verificar o valor de `nome` vindo no JSON e comparar com o texto do link, você pode jogar o o respectivo valor de `categoria` no seu link.

Basta inserir no `for` do `.each()` um `if` fazendo a comparação (explicações no código).

Nem precisa fazer concatenações, portanto a variável `var n = '';` é dispensável:

```
$(function(){
   var nome_a = ['home', 'fotos', 'contato', 'perfil', 'painel'];
   //    var n = '';

   var el = $('ul');
   for(var i = 0; i < nome_a.length; i ++){
      //        console.log('<li><a>'+nome_a[i]+'</a></li>');
      const y = '<li><a>'+nome_a[i]+'</a></li>';
      el.append(y);
   }
   //configura atribute href no elemento <a>
   $.ajax({
      url: 'conecta.php',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json'
   }).done(function(data){
      $('a').each(function(i, e){

         // pego o texto do link
         var nome = $(e).text();

         for(var i = 0; i < data.produto.length; i++){

            // verifico se a chave "nome" é igual ao texto do link
            if(data.produto[i].nome == nome){

               // se forem iguais, atribuo o "href" com o valor
               // da chave "categoria"
               $(e).attr('href', data.produto[i].categoria);
               break; // paro o laço, pois já encontrei o que queria
            }
         }
      }) 
   }).fail(function(){
      console.log("Erro no carregamento das categorias");
   })
})
```

**Resultado:**

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#home">home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#fotos">fotos</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#contato">contato</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#perfil">perfil</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#painel">painel</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque não montas o **html** que desejas já no `callback` do **ajax** ? exemplo (não testado)

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'produto.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response){
        var data = $('ul');
        response.forEach(function(produto) {
            console.log(produto);
                data.append(
                     $("<li></li>").append(
                         $('<a></a>').attr('href', produto.categoria)
                    )
                );
            }

        });
    }) 
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("Erro no carregamento das categorias");
    })
```